# Python counting up (1+2+3 etc.) until input value

Tags: python, loops

How to keep counting up (1+2+3) until user input value?

This is my code so far,

```
until = int(input("Keep counting until: "))

x = 1

while until >= x:

    x = x + 1

print(x)
```

I can't figure out how to keep increasing the value by one at a time... the goal should be

e.g if input value was `2` to print `3` and if `10`, `10` and `18`,  `21`.

Comment: What is the expected output for 10? I thought it would be 55 if you are adding all the consecutive integers?

Comment: expected would be 10, 

1+2 = 3
3 + 3 = 6
6 + 4 = 10

Comment: Your code as written always outputs `until + 1`. It's not at all clear what you want to do that `10` would produce `10` but `18` would produce `21`.

Comment: `1 -> 1`, `2 -> 3`, `3 -> 6`, `4 -> 10`, ..., `10 -> 55`, ..., `18 -> 171`, etc. (if you want `sum(range(1, until + 1))`.

Comment: You seem to be confusing `x` (the current value in the implied range 1 to until) with the sum of `x` and all *previous* values of `x`.

Comment: the sum of n integers is given by formulae -> `print((until * (until + 1))/2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is you always do `x + 1`, but you want `x + i` where `i` increments each time. Then you want to stop when `x < until` not when `x <= until`.

This will do what you need:

```
until = int(input("Keep counting until: "))

x = 0
i=0
while x < until:
    i+=1
    x = x + i

print(x)
```

Example output:

```
Keep counting until: 18
21
```

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks, updated.